# Tslearn(time series machine learn package of pyhon) can only receive 1 dimentional time series data as feature input?

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series

I'm using python tslearn package to do some stock price forecasting. But it seems like that the tslearn can only use 1 dimensional time series data as input, for example the close price series.

I really want to know if tslearn can also process 2 or higher dimensional input features, for instance, one close price time series, and one volume time series. Then it can maybe make the prediction more accurate.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what makes you think `tslearn` could work on monodimensional data only.

As stated in the [getting started](https://tslearn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gettingstarted.html) page of the docs, each time series is:

> a two-dimensional `numpy` array with its first dimension corresponding to the time axis and the second one being the feature dimensionality (1 by default).

This way, a time series dataset is a 3d-array of shape `(n, T, d)` where `n` is the number of time series in the dataset, `T` their length and `d` their dimensionality/number of modalities.

All metrics / estimators / etc. accept multidimensional time series unless otherwise stated in the docs. If I remember correctly, `KShape` is the only estimator to be restricted to monodimensional time series.